# Aviation Acronyms

Tags: discussion, faq, acronyms

Aviation is full of acronyms that are very often not obvious.

Where can we look if we come across one that we aren't familiar with?

Answer (score 6):

If you have come across an acronym that you aren't familiar with, here are a few places to look:

- [The Pilot Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg/index.htm) on the FAA's website
- Search [our own list of tags](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags), which will usually have a bit more information than the Pilot Controller Glossary
- Do a search on your favorite search engine for `aviation <acronym>`
- If all else fails, [post a comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on the question/answer asking the author to clarify!

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia also presents a nice list: [List of aviation, aerospace and aeronautical abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aviation,_aerospace_and_aeronautical_abbreviations)

From there, you can get to the relevant article for further details.

Answer (score 2):

FAA - Order JO 7340.1Z [Contractions](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ND/7340.1Z.pdf) (561 p.)

> This handbook contains the approved word and phrase contractions used
>   by personnel of the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) and other
>   agencies th at provide air traffic control, communications, weather,
>   charting, and associated aviation communication services. Also
>   contained are aircraft-type designators; civil aircraft company
>   three-letter identifiers and telephony designator assignments;
>   aircraft nationality assignments; and civil/military aircraft-type
>   designators

---

AAA - [All Aviation Abbreviations](http://www.flyingineurope.be/all_aviation_abbreviations.htm) (55 p.)

> A list of more than 7000 aviation abbreviations and acronyms are
>   commonly used in aviation and may be found throughout aviation
>   legislation, operational manuals, in the AIP, on associated
>   aeronautical charts and maps, in NOTAMs, in AIP supplements in
>   meteorological messages etc. The abbreviations and acronyms have been
>   sourced from and are used in various areas, such as ICAO, AIP, IATA,
>   FAA, Metar, Taf, Notam and Jeppesen and many other documents.

---

[Aviation Electronics Glossary](https://www.scribd.com/doc/19853328/Aviation-Electronics-Glossary-Rockwell-Collins) (Rockwell Collins)
(At Scribd)

> Avionics-ese. Sometimes called AV-Speak. It’s a confusing, sometimes
>   frustrating language. That’s why your friends at Rockwell Collins
>   created this handy. compendium of acronyms, terms and definitions. We
>   hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[ICAO Doc 8400 - Abbreviations and Codes](http://www1.atmb.net.cn/CD_web/UploadFile/2013052810480238.pdf)